# Form for showing diaper prices

Tags: c#, beginner, calculator, winforms

Here's a small program to tell our employees the price of our diapers. Is there a way such as an int array or an optimized way to set brandLevelNumber & sizeLevelNumber to the selected items in the brandComboBox & the sizeComboBox?

Also, do you guys think there's a better way for the method calculatePricePerDiaper() to work than a switch within a switch, or any other suggestions at all? I just started coding about a year ago, so any feedback will be appreciated.

The only case for brandLevelNumber is 0 because I haven't finished it yet with the methodology I had in mind, but rather just wrote enough for that brandLevelNumber to work.

This information was gathered across various websites (Walmart.com, Target.Com, etc.) and compiled in Excel.

```
class Diaper
{

    public string brandLevel;
    public string sizeLevel;
    public int brandLevelNumber;
    public int sizeLevelNumber;

    public string[] brands = {"Earth's Best", "Huggies Snug & Dry", "Huggies Snugglers & Movers",
                              "Luvs", "Pampers Baby Dry", "Pampers Swaddlers & Cruisers", "Seventh Generation",
                        "Store"};
    public string[] size = {"Size 1", "Size 2", "Size 3", "Size 4", "Size 5", "Size 6 & 7",
                            "Size N","2T-3T", "3T-4T", "4T-5T","Big Kids" };
    public double count;
    public double price;
    private double pricePerDiaper;
    public double finalPrice;


    public double calculatePricePerDiaper()
    {

            switch (brandLevelNumber)
            {
                case 0:
                    switch (sizeLevelNumber)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (count > 0 && count < 50)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 50 && count <= 160)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            if (count > 160)
                                pricePerDiaper = 0.10;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (count > 0 && count <= 42)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.13;
                            if (count > 42 && count <=105)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 150)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                             if (count > 0 && count <=36)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.16;
                            if (count >36)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=31)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.18;
                            if (count > 31 && count <=85)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.15;
                            if (count >85)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.14;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=28)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.21;
                            if (count > 28 && count <= 100)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.17;
                            if (count > 100)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.16;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.24;
                            if (count > 25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.20;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=50)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
                            if (count > 50)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=30)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.23;
                            if (count >30 && count <= 160)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.22;
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=25)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.26;
                            if (count > 25 && count <= 55)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.25;
                            if (count > 61)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.24;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=22)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.32;
                            if (count > 22 && count <= 40)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.31;
                            if (count > 40 && count <= 60)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.29;
                            if (count>60)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.27;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            if (count > 0 && count <=20)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.41;
                            if (count > 20 && count <= 37)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.37;
                            if (count >37)
                            pricePerDiaper = 0.36;
                            break;
                    }
                break;
            }

        return pricePerDiaper;
    }
    public double calculatePrice(double pricePerDiaper, double count)
    {
        price = pricePerDiaper * count;
        return price;
    }

}


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Diaper item = new Diaper();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            brandComboBox.DataSource = item.brands;
            sizeComboBox.DataSource = item.size;
  }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make the comboboxes appear empty at initial load
        //brandComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
        //sizeComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    private void countTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //So exception isn't thrown if user deletes countTextBox.Text
        string i = countTextBox.Text;
        if (double.TryParse(i, out item.count))
            item.count = Convert.ToDouble(countTextBox.Text);
    }

    private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.finalPrice=(item.calculatePrice(item.calculatePricePerDiaper(), Convert.ToDouble(countTextBox.Text)));
        priceLabel.Text = "$" + item.finalPrice;
    }

    private void brandComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.brandLevel = (string)brandComboBox.SelectedItem;
        switch (item.brandLevel)
        {
            case "Huggies Snug & Dry":
            case "Pampers Baby Dry":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 0;
                break;
            case "Earth's Best":
            case "Huggies Snugglers & Movers":
            case "Pampers Swaddlers & Cruisers":
            case "Seventh Generation":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 1;
                break;
            case "Luvs":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 2;
                break;
            case "Store":
                item.brandLevelNumber = 3;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sizeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.sizeLevel = (string)sizeComboBox.SelectedItem;
        switch (item.sizeLevel)
        {
            case "Size 1":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 1;
                break;
            case "Size 2":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 2;
                break;
            case "Size 3":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 3;
                break;
            case "Size 4":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 4;
                break;
            case "Size 5":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 5;
                break;
            case "Size 6 & 7":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 6;
                break;
            case "Size N":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 7;
                break;
            case "2T-3T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 8;
                break;
            case "3T-4T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 9;
                break;
            case "4T-5T":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 10;
                break;
            case "Big Kids":
                item.sizeLevelNumber = 11;
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails on count = 50
You don't need the `count > 50 &&` at all

```
case 1:
    if (count > 0 && count < 50)
        pricePerDiaper = 0.12;
    if (count > 50 && count <= 160)
        pricePerDiaper = 0.11;
    if (count > 160)
        pricePerDiaper = 0.10;
        break;
```

You should pass to `brandLevelNumber` and `sizeLevelNumber` to `calculatePricePerDiaper()`

You can assign a integer value to an enum
With this you can get rid of a switch

```
public enum Weighted { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3, four = 4, once = 1}
int value = (int)Weighted.one;
```

All the integers must be unique